# problem in not replaceing minus sign(-) with a blank using regex

Tags: regex, special-characters

I am using this regex expression to replace some characters with `""` 
I used it as

```
query=query.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9 * ? :  . + - ^ "" _]+/g,'');
```

But when my query is as `+White+Diamond`, i get result `+White+Diamond`, but when query is `-White+diamond` i am getting `White+diamond`, it means `-` is replaced by `""` that i don't want. 
Please tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What SteeveDroz said:

```
query=query.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9*?:.+\-^"_ ]+/g,'');
```

I'm assuming you want to exclude spaces as well. If not, remove the final space from the character class.

Answer (score 5):

In regex, `-` means "from ... to ...", escape your `-` with a backslash: `\-`.

Comment: Or put it at the end or beginning of the class.

Comment: @Romi In this case, it `+ - ^` means "plus, from *white space* to *white space*, cirumflex". BTW, you don't need spaces between characters in a `[]`.